# GWT Designer Componentry

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-designer

I'm brand new to GWT and am using the *GWT Designer* to help acclimate me to it. So far I've been able to get a few simple examples up and running locally, but after trying to figure out how to do a few things myself, and not being able to find answers to them in the GWT docs, I have a few questions regarding the Designer and its usage:

1. How do I create an HTML table, or a **TableLayout**? Although the docs show the existence of a `TableLayout`, I don't see it available in the Designer palette (even under the **Cell Widgets** section). Basically, I want the ability to organize my widgets in a tabular fashion and can't figure out how to do it.
2. When (taking into account "GWT Best Practices" and other procedures that the GWT team endorses/encourages) should one use `SafeHTML`, and why? How does the Designer promote this? I don't see any "Safe HTML" widgets in the Designer palette.
3. In order to create an interesting UI of any nature, I find myself nesting panels, inside of panels, inside of yet more panels (like you would in Swing). Is this the normal way of doing things in GWT, or am I making things more complicated than I need to?
4. I'm beginning to understand how to use the GWT Designer to design individual panels, or "portions" of a page, but how/where do you actually design the layout/configuration of the entire page? For instance, 1 page might have 5 different major `HorizontalPanel`s, each of which contain an intricate nesting of other panels and widgets. How do you layout each of the major panels so as to produce a full-fledged page?

Thanks in advance for any help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `Cell` library was meant to extended from the ground up, so yes, you need to write this functionality yourself.
2. The GWT Designer is meant to be a tool for GWT newcomers, and lacks some of the more sopisticated features (such a the Safe* API). As @Jason Tholtstrup noted, this framework is for helping to prevent against XSS and XSRF attacks.
3. Yes, just like Swing: panels inside of panels inside of panels. It's like Inception.
4. You organize your page into different *display regions*, which you lay out via CSS rules (see `CssResource` and `ClientBundle`). Each display region is actually an `AcceptsOneWidget` implementation, which you pass to whatever mechanism (usually a `Presenter` or an `Activity` implementation) you are using to control the view-portion of the app.

Answer (score 0):

2) Safe html will help protect you from Cross-site-scripting attacks.  Basically it escapes data (which may have come from a user) so that malicious html can't be injected from your application variables.

3) Yes, pretty much how it works.

hope that helps